# inlines forms django no muestra detalle

Tags: django

estoy trabajando con un par de tablas en una relación uno a muchos (persona->tareas). La relación funciona bien, ya que se crean los IDs correspondientes y puedo hacer join de ambas tablas en sql.
Entiendo que en el modulo de administración, puedo declarar estas tablas, de modo tal que la plataforma me provee de un CRUD para manipular los datos.
Estoy intentando usar Inlines Forms, para que el administrador, me pueda mostrar para cada persona, sus tareas.
este es el codigo del admin.py:

```html
from .models import Persona, Tarea
admin.site.register(Persona)
admin.site.register(Tarea)

class TareaInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Tarea 
  extra = 2

class PersonaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('nombre', 'edad')
  inlines = [TareaInline]
```

Según leo en la documentación que he encontrado, esto debería mostrar el nombre y la edad de la persona (si lo hace) y debajo, una lista de tareas (no lo muestra)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con versiones 3.1, y 2.2 de django, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Estoy usando la bd por defecto db-sqlite3
Aca los datos de las tablas que tengo para este ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna Idea de porque no funcione?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código no le dices que formulario debe usar el admin, con estos cambios debería funcionar, en lo personal me gusta más usar un decorador:

```
from .models import Persona, Tarea

class TareaInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Tarea 
  extra = 2

@admin.register(Persona)
class PersonaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('nombre', 'edad')
  inlines = [TareaInline]
```

Comment: Hola, si, me acabo de dar cuenta de mi error..  al registrar, no estaba agregando la clase PersonaAdmin lo correcto seria: admin.site.register(Persona, PersonaAdmin). Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudó la respuesta, vi tu pregunta en Django Chile, pero preferí responder por acá, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco porque no funcina, pero puedes tratar de usar

`TabularInline`

[La documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline)

```
from .models import Persona, Tarea

class TareaInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Tarea 
  extra = 2

@admin.register(Persona)
class PersonaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('nombre', 'edad')
  inlines = [TareaInline]
```

Espero ayude de algo

Comment: Estaba cometiendo un error en el register..  lo correcto es admin.site.register(Persona, PersonaAdmin). Gracias por tu respuesta